# Tweepy Hipchat API - Except rate limit?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have this code to get followers of a twitter user:

```
followers=[]
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers,id=uNameInput).items():
    followers.append(user.screen_name)
```

However if this is used on a user with multiple followers, the script gets a rate limit and stops. I would usually put this in a while true; try, except else break loop but unsure where it would go in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid rate limit, you can/should wait before the next follower page request:

```
for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, id=uNameInput).items():
    followers.append(user.screen_name)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Doesn't look beautiful, but should help.

UPD: According to the official [twitter limits](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits), you can make only 30 requests per 15-minute interval to get `followers`.

So, you can either catch rate limit exception and wait for 15 minutes interval to end, or define a counter and make sure you don't make more than 30 requests per 15-minute gap.

Here's an example, how you can catch the tweepy exception and wait for 15 minutes before moving to the next portion of followers:

```
import time
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(..., ...)
auth.set_access_token(..., ...)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
items = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="gvanrossum").items()

while True:
    try:
        item = next(items)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        time.sleep(60 * 15)
        item = next(items)

    print item
```

Not sure this is the best approach though.

UPD2: There is also another option: you can check for [rate_limit_status](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/application/rate_limit_status), see how much requests remain for `followers` and decide whether to wait or continue.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem with this is, it waits no matter what. So if used on someone with little followers it would wait a minute before processing the data.

Comment: Thanks for that, the counter option seems a bit sketchy to me and would prefer to catch the rate limit then wait. The problem is I dont know where to stick it. Would I need to expand the loop?

Comment: @Martyn, I've added a code sample and another option (see `UPD2`).

Comment: Thats great thanks. Wont your while loop need and else break?

Comment: @Martyn, yeah, sure, you'll need to exit the loop eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a more precise way to do this with the new rate_limit_status' reset attribute. Whereas @alecxe's answer forces you to wait 15 minutes each time, even if the window is much smaller, you can instead wait just the right amount of time and no longer by doing:

```
import time
import tweepy
import calendar
import datetime

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(..., ...)
auth.set_access_token(..., ...)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
items = tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name="gvanrossum").items()

while True:
    try:
        item = next(items)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        #Rate limited. Checking when to try again
        rate_info = api.rate_limit_status()['resources']
        reset_time = rate_info['followers']['/followers/ids']['reset']
        cur_time = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timetuple())
        #wait the minimum time necessary plus a few seconds to be safe
        try_again_time = reset_time - cur_time + 5
        #Will try again in try_again_time seconds...
        time.sleep(try_again_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
try:
    followers=[]
    for user in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers,id=uNameInput).items():
        followers.append(user.screen_name)
except: 
    errmsg = str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    printdebug(errmsg)
    if errmsg.find("'code': 88") != -1: # [{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded', 'code': 88}]
        print("Blocked.")
        time.sleep(60 * 60) # Wait 1 hour for unblock
        pass
    else:
        raise
```